# Is it okay for a parent to cry in front of their children?

Tags: development, parents, crying

If it's okay for a parent to cry in fron of their children, when and in what circumstances will it not affect their children in a negative way?

Comment: I think you will find the answer to this question here. https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/7828/is-it-appropriate-for-parents-to-cry-in-front-of-their-children